# Not expected value xMidYMid meet when interpreting the preserveAspectRatio attribute

Tags: html, web, svg, warnings, firebug

I'm getting the above warning with Firebug in my web application, but I've not been able to find out what is generating it. It seems to be a `svg` attribute, but I don't have any `svg` files in the web site. The web site is http://itransformer.es

Any idea of what's causing the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on the error in the browser console the file containing the error will be shown.

SVG is case sensitive. The bit being complained about is `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYmid meet"` which should be `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"` note the capital M both times.

This seems to be something called fastbutton from Google (https://apis.google.com/u/0/) so you should report the error to them.

Comment: Thanks Robert -- it is an issue in the +1 button payload.  I'll talk to the people responsible and get it fixed.

Comment: This issue has been resolved.  You should not see this error message any longer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Robert is correct you can get more info from here:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute

The problem in in your website, same mine is that your social google+1 is sending a wrong parameter to the **preserveAspectRatio**.

preserveAspectRatio="xMidYmid meet"  Wrong!
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"  Correct!

Unfortunately the solution is not in your hands :(